# Restore backup from internal storage

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, data-recovery, usb-debugging

**My first problem:**

My Google Play had a persistent "No connection" error.
There are a bunch of fixes but none of them worked.
So I decided to try the final fix: Restore device.
Now I knew this would delete most my data (Rest stored in Google Account cloud).
So I looked into backup software for my laptop (since I couldn't get backup software on the play store).

**My second problem:**

I'm a recently started Android developer so I had the SDK and USB driver. Now I tried to push my software to the device through USB but USB debugging wasn't working (Yes my debugging is on, yes I've tried everything to fix my debugging problem).

**So then:**

When I couldn't get backup software on my android OR my computer I thought just copying the data off my device (my computer could see the device as a media device, so I could see the files on my computer just couldn't get USB debugging on).

**My third problem:**

So I copied everything I could and saved it to my computer.
Restored my device.
Dragged all the files back onto the Android.
Didn't work.
Is there anyway I can get those files back onto my device?
Is has folders such as: Android, DCIM, Download, Movies, Picture, Storage etc...

**TL;DR:**

My Play Store isn't working. (It now does after the reset).

My USB Debugging isn't working.

I can't get my "backup" back onto my device.

If anyone could fix any or all of these problems, that would be amazing, if you need anymore info let me know!

Comment: Typically, you should only ask 1 question at a time. it allows a person to specifically answer, and it to be accepted. if I know the answer to one of your questions, my answer would be "incomplete". - Your 3rd problem, shouldn't be a problem. Those folders live on the internal/external storage, they are not in a location that is wiped when you do a factory reset. They should still be there.